# Add a local file in a markdown file

Tags: html, pdf, markdown

I ran a FastQC pipeline which gave me a `.html` file. I can open up this file because it is on my C: disk (`C:\Users\my_name\Documents`) , it opens me a HTML page (logic!) .

I am creating a markdown file on GitLab. What I would like to do is to add this file into my `.md` file in order than anyone of my teamwork can see that `.html` file. And later, I will convert that `.md` file in a pdf file that everyone could read in the world.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Add it how? So that the HTML source is readable as an inline code block, or so that the HTML is rendered as part of the rendered markdown (I'm not sure that's possible), or as an attachment that people can download from the rendered markdown (I don't think that's possible either)

Comment: Yes sorry, I dind't specify how. So that the HTML source is readable as an inline code block.